# react native data type for xml for functions

Tags: react-native

I want to make a function that takes in either  or

the function is called navigate so it looks like this

```
about(view: ?){
}
```

what do I put in place of the question mark so i can take in xml values?

Comment: I didn't get this question.

Comment: if you want to take a number as a parameter you make your function

clicked(id: number){}

What happens if you want to take <Main></Main> as an argument?

Comment: What is the purpose of passing <Main> in function?